# Pita Bread-Why is one side too thin?

Tags: sourdough, flatbread, pita

Is there a way to avoid having one side (top or bottom) of the pita bread much thinner than the other side? The thin side is very prone to ripping if I try to fill it. I make whole wheat sourdough pita bread using white hard wheat or hard red spring wheat that I grind in my Mockmill (just flour, sourdough starter, water, and a tiny bit of salt). I ferment the dough for 6-8 hours and sometimes refrigerate it after fermentation time for a few days. I often get better puffing after refrigerating the dough. I get the best results (almost all pitas puffing) when I bake them in a 475-degree convection gas oven on a heavy pizza stone preheated for at least half an hour or more. I get a nice puff on most of them, and most will separate after cutting them in half. I just wish I could bake them so that the thin side is not so thin as to be prone to tearing when filling them. Also, I would appreciate tips for getting pitas to puff when cooked on the stovetop. Thank you for your suggestions!